# Using maclaurin expansion find the limit $\lim e^{1/x}(x^3-x^2+x/2)-(x^3+x^6)^{0.5}$ as x approaches infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

I tried to write -
$$e^x = 1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+\alpha(x)x^3$$
$$e^{1/x}=1+1/x + 1/2x^2 + 1/6x^3 + \alpha (1/x)/x^3$$

That did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Make $x=\frac 1 y$, replace and simplify to obtain
$$\frac{e^y (y^2-2 y+2)-2 \sqrt{y^3+1}}{2 y^3}$$

Now, use the series for small $y$